# How can I get or print current datetime of GMT time zone in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, utc, gmt

***Here I print UTC time zone's current datetime. I want current GMT time zone's datetime by this method. How can I?***

```
   import datetime

   dt_utcnow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
   print(dt_utcnow)
```

***Output***

```
   2020-08-31 09:06:26.661323
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert datetime.time from UTC to different timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603645/how-to-convert-datetime-time-from-utc-to-different-timezone)

Comment: **UTC** is **GMT**  :-)

Comment: `from datetime import datetime, timezone`
`utc_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Comment: GMT and UTC are within a second of each other but they are not the same. If you need accuracy within 1 second then they are not interchangeably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the gmtime() of time module to achieve this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import gmtime, strftime

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
print("Your Time Zone is GMT", strftime("%z", gmtime()))
```

Comment: Actually I wanted like this. Thanks sir. <3

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to import pytz module (you need to install it using CMD: `pip install pytz`). Pytz library allows you to work with time zones.

To make code clear, we will save timezone into the variable GMT like this:

```
GMT = pytz.timezone("Etc/GMT")
```

If you want to now all possible timezones, you can just print out `pytz.all_timezones`. Now, there are several ways how to solve your problem, but I will show you 2 of them:

1. Localize your UTC time into GMT: `dt_gmt = GMT.localize(dt_utcnow)`
2. Convert your time into GMT:  `dt_gmt = dt_utcnow.astimezone(gmt)`

Comment: Thanks brother. But when I try to install pytz by pip "pip install pytz". But it shows that "Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\jjj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages". What is the solution?

Comment: It's alright. It just says that you have already installed this library. c:\users\... is just location of the library on your PC.

Comment: But I can't import it. HOw can I?